# Como mostrar un resultado pre marcado de una base de datos en un select con PHP, HTML, JS

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, select, mariadb, html-select

estoy haciendo una página editar de los registros de una tabla de mi base de datos, y logré que los input y radio buttons me muestren por default el valor que ya tiene el registro en la base de datos previo a la edición, pero no puedo lograr hacer lo mismo con los select.
Necesito que los select me muestren seleccionado el valor que tiene el registro actualmente en la base de datos, pero no sé como hacerlo, el select es dinámico, está compuesto por todas las empresas que estén cargadas en la tabla empresas en la base de datos.
Estructura del select:

```html
<label for="empresa" class="form-label">Empresa <font color="red">*</font></label>
  <select id="empresa" name="empresa" class="form-select" required>
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected"></option>
  <?php while ($empresas = mysqli_fetch_array($cmd)) {
  echo '<option value="'.$empresas['OID'].'">'.$empresas['nombre'].'</option>';
  } ?>                   
  </select>
  <div class="invalid-feedback">Por favor seleccione una empresa!</div>
```

Y el valor que necesito que quede pre cargado lo traigo en mi consulta en la variable
$fk_emp = $data['fk_empresa'];
que ese dato es igual al value que pongo en el select.
Si alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradecería.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el "option default" debes colocar los datos que ya has rescatado.

```
$fk_emp_id = $data['fk_empresa_id']; // ID
$fk_emp = $data['fk_empresa']; // nombre

<label for="empresa" class="form-label">Empresa <font color="red">*</font></label>
<select id="empresa" name="empresa" class="form-select" required>
    <!-- Esta línea -->
    <option value="<?php echo $fk_emp_id; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $fk_emp; ?></option>
    <!-- End esta línea -->
    <?php while ($empresas = mysqli_fetch_array($cmd)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$empresas['OID'].'">'.$empresas['nombre'].'</option>';
    } ?>                   
</select>
<div class="invalid-feedback">Por favor seleccione una empresa!</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono a la perfección!!

Comment: @Vale Me alegra. Protip: si te fijas bien, yo mando a "imprimir" solo las variables PHP, sería bueno que hicieras lo mismo, que te acostumbres desde ya que imprimir HTML desde PHP no es buena practica...